# how to segment and get the time between two dates?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, timescaledb

I have the following table:

```
id | number_of _trip |      start_date      |      end_date       | seconds
1     637hui           2022-03-10 01:20:00    2022-03-10 01:32:00    720  
2     384nfj           2022-03-10 02:18:00    2022-03-10 02:42:00    1440
3     102fiu           2022-03-10 02:10:00    2022-03-10 02:23:00    780
4     948pvc           2022-03-10 02:40:00    2022-03-10 03:20:00    2400
5     473mds           2022-03-10 02:45:00    2022-03-10 02:58:00    780
6     103fkd           2022-03-10 03:05:00    2022-03-10 03:28:00    1380
7     905783           2022-03-10 03:12:00             null           0 
8     498wsq           2022-03-10 05:30:00    2022-03-10 05:48:00    1080
```

I want to get the time that is driven for each hour, but if a trip takes the space of two hours, the time must be taken for each hour.
If the end of the trip has not yet finished, the `end_date` field is null, but it must count the time it is taking in the respective hours from `start_date`.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT time_bucket(bucket_width := INTERVAL '1 hour',ts := start_date, "offset" := '0 minutes') AS init_date,
       sum(seconds) as seconds
        FROM trips
        WHERE start_date >= '2022-03-10 01:00:00' AND start_date <= '2022-03-10 06:00:00'
        GROUP BY init_date
        ORDER BY init_date;
```

The result is:

```
|   init_date         | seconds 
  2022-03-10 01:00:00    720
  2022-03-10 02:00:00    5400
  2022-03-10 03:00:00    1380
  2022-03-10 05:00:00    1080
```

However I expect to receive a result like this:

```
|   init_date         | seconds     solo como una ayuda visual
  2022-03-10 01:00:00    720          id(1:720)
  2022-03-10 02:00:00    4200         id(2: 1440 3: 780 4: 1200 5: 780)
  2022-03-10 03:00:00    5460         id(4:1200 6:1380 7:2880)
  2022-03-10 05:00:00    1080         id(8:1080)
```

**EDIT**
If I replace the null the result is still unwanted:

```
|   init_date       | seconds 
2022-03-10 01:00:00   720
2022-03-10 02:00:00   5400
2022-03-10 03:00:00   1380
2022-03-10 05:00:00   1080
```

I have been thinking about getting all the data and solving the problem with pandas. I'll try and post if I get the answer.
**EDIT**

My previous result was not entirely correct, since there were hours left of a trip that has not yet finished, the correct result should be:

```
       start_date  seconds
0 2022-03-10 01:00:00      720
1 2022-03-10 02:00:00     4200
2 2022-03-10 03:00:00     5460
3 2022-03-10 04:00:00     3600
4 2022-03-10 05:00:00     4680
```

**NEW CODE**

```
def bucket_count(bucket, data):
    result = pd.DataFrame()
    list_r = []

    for row_bucket in bucket.to_dict('records'):
        inicio = row_bucket['start_date']
        fin = row_bucket['end_date']

        df = data[
                (inicio <= data['end_date']) & (inicio <= fin) & (data['start_date'] <= fin) & (data['start_date'] <= data['end_date'])
        ]
        df_dict = df.to_dict('records')

        for row in df_dict:
            seconds = 0
            if row['start_date'] >= inicio and fin >= row['end_date']:
                seconds = (row['end_date'] - row['start_date']).total_seconds()
            elif row['start_date'] <= inicio <= row['end_date'] <= fin:
                seconds = (row['end_date'] - inicio).total_seconds()
            elif inicio <= row['start_date'] <= fin <= row['end_date']:
                seconds = (fin - row['start_date']).total_seconds()
            elif row['start_date'] < inicio and fin < row['end_date']:
                seconds = (fin - inicio).total_seconds()

            row['start_date'] = inicio
            row['end_date'] = fin
            row['seconds'] = seconds
            list_r.append(row)

    result = pd.DataFrame(list_r)
    return result.groupby(['start_date'])["seconds"].apply(lambda x: x.astype(int).sum()).reset_index()
```

Comment: Replace current time if end time is null

Comment: What is your SQL engine? MySQL, Hive, Presto, etc?

Comment: @Bahman It's tagged `timescaledb` - so it's PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in plain sql (apart from `time_bucket` function), in a nested sql query:

```
select 
    interval_start, 
    sum(seconds_before_trip_ended - seconds_before_trip_started) as seconds
from (
    select 
        interval_start,
        greatest(0, extract(epoch from start_date - interval_start)::int) as seconds_before_trip_started,
        least(3600, extract(epoch from coalesce(end_date, '2022-03-10 06:00:00') - interval_start)::int) as seconds_before_trip_ended
    from (
        select generate_series(
            (select min(time_bucket(bucket_width := INTERVAL '1 hour', ts := start_date, "offset" := '0 minutes')) from trips),
            (select max(time_bucket(bucket_width := INTERVAL '1 hour', ts := coalesce(end_date, '2022-03-10 06:00:00'), "offset" := '0 minutes')) from trips),
            '1 hour') as interval_start) i
    join trips t
        on t.start_date <= i.interval_start + interval '1 hour'
        and coalesce(t.end_date, '2022-03-10 06:00:00') >= interval_start
    ) subq
group by interval_start
order by interval_start;
```

This gives me the following result:

```
   interval_start    | seconds
---------------------+---------
 2022-03-10 01:00:00 |     720
 2022-03-10 02:00:00 |    4200
 2022-03-10 03:00:00 |    5460
 2022-03-10 04:00:00 |    3600
 2022-03-10 05:00:00 |    4680
 2022-03-10 06:00:00 |       0
(6 rows)
```

### Explanation

Let's break the query down.

In the innermost query:

```
select generate_series(
        (select min(time_bucket(bucket_width := INTERVAL '1 hour', ts := start_date, "offset" := '0 minutes')) from trips),
        (select max(time_bucket(bucket_width := INTERVAL '1 hour', ts := coalesce(end_date, '2022-03-10 06:00:00'), "offset" := '0 minutes')) from trips),
        '1 hour'
    ) as interval_start
```

we generate a series of time interval starts - from minimal `start_date` value up to the maximal `end_time` value, truncated to full hours, with 1-hour step. Each boundary can obviously be replaced with an arbitrary datetime. Direct result of this query is the following:

```
   interval_start
---------------------
 2022-03-10 01:00:00
 2022-03-10 02:00:00
 2022-03-10 03:00:00
 2022-03-10 04:00:00
 2022-03-10 05:00:00
 2022-03-10 06:00:00
(6 rows)
```

Then, the middle-level query joins this series with the `trips` table, joining rows if and only if any part of the trip took place during the hour-long interval beginning at the time given by the 'interval_start' column:

```
select interval_start,
    greatest(0, extract(epoch from start_date - interval_start)::int) as seconds_before_trip_started,
    least(3600, extract(epoch from coalesce(end_date, '2022-03-10 06:00:00') - interval_start)::int) as seconds_before_trip_ended
from (
    -- innermost query
    select generate_series(
        (select min(time_bucket(bucket_width := INTERVAL '1 hour', ts := start_date, "offset" := '0 minutes')) from trips),
        (select max(time_bucket(bucket_width := INTERVAL '1 hour', ts := coalesce(end_date, '2022-03-10 06:00:00'), "offset" := '0 minutes')) from trips),
        '1 hour'
    ) as interval_start
    -- innermost query end
) intervals
join trips t
    on t.start_date <= intervals.interval_start + interval '1 hour' and coalesce(t.end_date, '2022-03-10 06:00:00') >= intervals.interval_start
```

The two computed values represent respectively:

- `seconds_before_trip_started` - number of second passed between the beginning of the interval, and the beginning of the trip (or 0 if the trip begun prior to interval start). This is the time the trip **didn't** take place - thus we will be substructing it in the following step
- `seconds_before_trip_ended` - number of seconds passed between the end of the interval, and the end of the trip (or 3600 if the trip didn't end within concerned interval).

The outermost query substracts the two beformentioned fields, effectively computing the time each trip took in each interval, and sums it for all trips, grouping by interval:

```
select 
    interval_start, 
    sum(seconds_before_trip_ended - seconds_before_trip_started) as seconds
from (
-- middle-level query
    select 
        interval_start,
        greatest(0, extract(epoch from start_date - interval_start)::int) as seconds_before_trip_started,
        least(3600, extract(epoch from coalesce(end_date, '2022-03-10 06:00:00') - interval_start)::int) as seconds_before_trip_ended
    from (
        select generate_series(
            (select min(time_bucket(bucket_width := INTERVAL '1 hour', ts := start_date, "offset" := '0 minutes')) from trips),
            (select max(time_bucket(bucket_width := INTERVAL '1 hour', ts := coalesce(end_date, '2022-03-10 06:00:00'), "offset" := '0 minutes')) from trips),
            '1 hour') as interval_start) i
    join trips t
        on t.start_date <= i.interval_start + interval '1 hour'
        and coalesce(t.end_date, '2022-03-10 06:00:00') >= interval_start
-- middle-level query end
    ) subq
group by interval_start
order by interval_start;
```

### Additional grouping

In case we have another column in the table, and what we really need is the segmentation of the above result in respect to that column, we simply need to add it to the appropriate `select` and `group by` clauses (optionally to `order by` clause as well).

Suppose there's an additional `driver_id` column in the `trips` table:

```
 id | number_of_trip |     start_date      |      end_date       | seconds | driver_id
----+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------
  1 | 637hui         | 2022-03-10 01:20:00 | 2022-03-10 01:32:00 |     720 |         0
  2 | 384nfj         | 2022-03-10 02:18:00 | 2022-03-10 02:42:00 |    1440 |         0
  3 | 102fiu         | 2022-03-10 02:10:00 | 2022-03-10 02:23:00 |     780 |         1
  4 | 948pvc         | 2022-03-10 02:40:00 | 2022-03-10 03:20:00 |    2400 |         1
  5 | 473mds         | 2022-03-10 02:45:00 | 2022-03-10 02:58:00 |     780 |         1
  6 | 103fkd         | 2022-03-10 03:05:00 | 2022-03-10 03:28:00 |    1380 |         2
  7 | 905783         | 2022-03-10 03:12:00 |                     |       0 |         2
  8 | 498wsq         | 2022-03-10 05:30:00 | 2022-03-10 05:48:00 |    1080 |         2
```

The modified query would look like that:

```
select
    interval_start,
    driver_id,
    sum(seconds_before_trip_ended - seconds_before_trip_started) as seconds
from (
    select 
        interval_start,
        driver_id,
        greatest(0, extract(epoch from start_date - interval_start)::int) as seconds_before_trip_started,
        least(3600, extract(epoch from coalesce(end_date, '2022-03-10 06:00:00') - interval_start)::int) as seconds_before_trip_ended
    from (
        select generate_series(
            (select min(time_bucket(bucket_width := INTERVAL '1 hour', ts := start_date, "offset" := '0 minutes')) from trips),
            (select max(time_bucket(bucket_width := INTERVAL '1 hour', ts := coalesce(end_date, '2022-03-10 06:00:00'), "offset" := '0 minutes')) from trips),
            '1 hour') as interval_start
    ) intervals
    join trips t
        on t.start_date <= intervals.interval_start + interval '1 hour'
        and coalesce(t.end_date, '2022-03-10 06:00:00') >= intervals.interval_start
) subq
group by interval_start, driver_id
order by interval_start, driver_id;
```

and give the following result:

```
   interval_start    | driver_id | seconds
---------------------+-----------+---------
 2022-03-10 01:00:00 |         0 |     720
 2022-03-10 02:00:00 |         0 |    1440
 2022-03-10 02:00:00 |         1 |    2760
 2022-03-10 03:00:00 |         1 |    1200
 2022-03-10 03:00:00 |         2 |    4260
 2022-03-10 04:00:00 |         2 |    3600
 2022-03-10 05:00:00 |         2 |    4680
 2022-03-10 06:00:00 |         2 |       0
```

Comment: The code returns the hours correctly, but if I have a column with the driver id, how do I get a segmentation by hours and by driver id?

Comment: @Isra It's just a matter of adding the column to `select` and `group by` clauses - in the edited answear I've included an example of such modified query.

Comment: WOW, This is the fastest code and by far, really thanks for the contribution

Comment: @Isra My pleasure :)

Answer (score 3):

> I have been thinking about getting all the data and solving the problem with pandas.

**TLDR:** Generate a range of minutes per trip, [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) those minutes into rows, and [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) those rows into hours to [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.count.html) the minutes per hour:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_sql(...)

# convert to datetime dtype if not already
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'])

# fill missing end dates
current_time = pd.Timestamp('2022-03-10 04:00:00') # or pd.Timestamp.now()
df['end_date'] = df['end_date'].fillna(current_time)

# generate range of minutes per trip
df['init_date'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['start_date'], x['end_date'], freq='min', inclusive='left'), axis=1)

(df[['id', 'init_date']].explode('init_date')          # explode minutes into rows
   .set_index('init_date')['id'].resample('H').count() # count rows (minutes) per hour
   .mul(60).reset_index(name='seconds'))               # convert minutes to seconds
```

Output:

```
init_date            seconds
2022-03-10 01:00:00  720
2022-03-10 02:00:00  4200
2022-03-10 03:00:00  5460
2022-03-10 04:00:00  0
2022-03-10 05:00:00  1080
```

---

### Step-by-step breakdown

1. Generate a [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) of minutes from `start_date` to `end_date` per trip:

   ```py
   df['init_date'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['start_date'], x['end_date'], freq='min', inclusive='left'), axis=1)

   # id  number_of_trip  ...  init_date
   # 1   637hui          ...  DatetimeIndex(['2022-03-10 01:20:00', '2022-03-10 01:21:00', ..., '2022-03-10 01:31:00'])
   # 2   384nfj          ...  DatetimeIndex(['2022-03-10 02:18:00', '2022-03-10 02:19:00', ..., '2022-03-10 01:41:00'])
   # 3   102fiu          ...  DatetimeIndex(['2022-03-10 02:10:00', '2022-03-10 02:11:00', ..., '2022-03-10 02:22:00'])
   # 4   948pvc          ...  DatetimeIndex(['2022-03-10 02:40:00', '2022-03-10 02:41:00', ..., '2022-03-10 03:19:00'])
   # 5   473mds          ...  DatetimeIndex(['2022-03-10 02:45:00', '2022-03-10 02:46:00', ..., '2022-03-10 02:57:00'])
   # 6   103fkd          ...  DatetimeIndex(['2022-03-10 03:05:00', '2022-03-10 03:06:00', ..., '2022-03-10 03:27:00'])
   # 7   905783          ...  DatetimeIndex(['2022-03-10 03:12:00', '2022-03-10 03:13:00', ..., '2022-03-10 03:59:00'])
   # 8   498wsq          ...  DatetimeIndex(['2022-03-10 05:30:00', '2022-03-10 05:31:00', ..., '2022-03-10 05:47:00'])
   ```
2. [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the minutes into rows:

   ```py
   exploded = df[['init_date', 'id']].explode('init_date').set_index('init_date')['id']

   # init_date
   # 2022-03-10 01:20:00    1
   # 2022-03-10 01:21:00    1
   # 2022-03-10 01:22:00    1
   #                       ..
   # 2022-03-10 05:45:00    8
   # 2022-03-10 05:46:00    8
   # 2022-03-10 05:47:00    8
   # Name: id, Length: 191, dtype: int64
   ```
3. [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) the rows into hours to [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.count.html) the minutes per hour (× 60 to convert to seconds):

   ```py
   out = exploded.resample('H').count().mul(60).reset_index(name='seconds')

   # init_date            seconds
   # 2022-03-10 01:00:00  720
   # 2022-03-10 02:00:00  4200
   # 2022-03-10 03:00:00  5460
   # 2022-03-10 04:00:00  0
   # 2022-03-10 05:00:00  1080
   ```

---

### Driver IDs

> If I have a column with the driver id, how do I get a segmentation by hours and by driver id without reprocessing?

In this case, just change [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) to [`groupby.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html). Select `driver_id` before exploding, and group by `driver_id` before resampling.

As a minimal example, I duplicated the sample data to create two `driver_id` groups `a` and `b`:

```
# after preprocessing and creating init_date ...

(df[['driver_id', 'init_date']]                        # now include driver_id
    .explode('init_date').set_index('init_date')       # explode minutes into rows
    .groupby('driver_id').resample('H').count()        # count rows (minutes) per hour per driver_id
    .mul(60).rename(columns={'driver_id': 'seconds'})) # convert minutes to seconds

#                                seconds
# driver_id init_date                   
# a         2022-03-10 01:00:00  720
#           2022-03-10 02:00:00  4200
#           2022-03-10 03:00:00  5460
#           2022-03-10 04:00:00  0
#           2022-03-10 05:00:00  1080
# b         2022-03-10 01:00:00  720
#           2022-03-10 02:00:00  4200
#           2022-03-10 03:00:00  5460
#           2022-03-10 04:00:00  0
#           2022-03-10 05:00:00  1080
```

Comment: The code returns the hours correctly, but if I have a column with the `driver id`, how do I get a segmentation by hours and by driver id without reprocessing? In my code I can save the `result` DataFrame and then just group by `start_date` and `driver id` or another column

Comment: @Isra It should just be a minor change from `resample` to `groupby.resample`. See if the updated "Driver ID" section is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes it works, although I have rows with trips that last seconds like `'2022-03-29 13:36:34' to '2022-03-29 13:36:51'`, for those cases the sum is not correct, but I guess I should change the frequency to `1S` and remove `mul(60)` for it to work, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yes you can change `init_date` to `freq='1S'` (but still resample to `1H`) and remove the `mul(60)`. Only thing is that generating/exploding `1S` ranges will be quite memory intensive. Might have to do it in chunks.

Comment: Yes, when making the change it works although the speed was greatly affected

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works in sqlite (can be tested):

```
CREATE TABLE trips(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  start_date TIMESTAMP,
  end_date TIMESTAMP,
  seconds INT
);

INSERT INTO trips(id, start_date, end_date, seconds) VALUES
  (1, '2022-03-10 01:20:00', '2022-03-10 01:32:00', 720),
  (2, '2022-03-10 02:18:00', '2022-03-10 02:42:00', 1440),
  (3, '2022-03-10 02:10:00', '2022-03-10 02:23:00', 780),
  (4, '2022-03-10 02:40:00', '2022-03-10 03:20:00', 2400),
  (5, '2022-03-10 02:45:00', '2022-03-10 02:58:00', 780),
  (6, '2022-03-10 03:05:00', '2022-03-10 03:28:00', 1380),
  (7, '2022-03-10 03:12:00', NULL, 0),
  (8, '2022-03-10 05:30:00', '2022-03-10 05:48:00', 1080);

WITH 
  checked AS (SELECT '2022-03-10 03:00:00' AS start, '2022-03-10 04:00:00' AS end)
SELECT
  SUM(
    IIF(end_date IS NULL, ROUND(MAX(0, (JULIANDAY(checked.end) - JULIANDAY(start_date)) * 24 * 60 * 60)),
      MAX(
        0,
        (JULIANDAY(MIN(checked.end, end_date)) - JULIANDAY(MAX(checked.start, start_date))) / 
          (JULIANDAY(end_date) - JULIANDAY(start_date)) * seconds
      )
    )
  )
FROM trips, checked;

DROP TABLE trips;
```

The code is simplified and sqlite lacks some features, but I think it will be easy to adapt :)

Briefly, the algorithm is:

- If end_time = NULL, then:

  - Calculate the number of seconds from the start of the trip to the end of the interval
  - Throw away negative values
- Otherwise:

  - Calculate what part of trip in seconds we need within one interval
  - Throw away negative values
- Sum the values

This can be done for any interval with a start and end

Answer (score 0):

This answer will use [staircase](https://www.staircase.dev), which is built upon pandas and numpy, and operates as part of the pandas ecosystem.

Your data describes intervals, which can be thought of as step functions which have a value of 1 during the interval and 0 otherwise.  Using `staircase` we will add the step functions for each trip together, slice the step function into hour buckets, and then integrate to get the total time for each bucket.

**setup**

Dataframe with `pandas.Timestamp`.  The trip number not relevant in this solution.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "start_date": [
        pd.Timestamp("2022-03-10 1:20"),
        pd.Timestamp("2022-03-10 2:18"),
        pd.Timestamp("2022-03-10 2:10"),
        pd.Timestamp("2022-03-10 2:40"),
        pd.Timestamp("2022-03-10 2:45"),
        pd.Timestamp("2022-03-10 3:05"),
        pd.Timestamp("2022-03-10 3:12"),
        pd.Timestamp("2022-03-10 5:30"),
    ],
    "end_date": [
        pd.Timestamp("2022-03-10 1:32"),
        pd.Timestamp("2022-03-10 2:42"),
        pd.Timestamp("2022-03-10 2:23"),
        pd.Timestamp("2022-03-10 3:20"),
        pd.Timestamp("2022-03-10 2:58"),
        pd.Timestamp("2022-03-10 3:28"),
        pd.NaT,
        pd.Timestamp("2022-03-10 5:48"),
    ],
})
```

**solution**

```
import staircase as sc

# create step function
# the Stairs class represents a step function.  It is to staircase as DataFrame is to pandas.
sf = sc.Stairs(df, start="start_date", end="end_date")

# you could visually inspect it if you want
sf.plot(style="hlines")
```

[image: step function plot]

From inspection you can see the maximum concurrent trips is 3.  Also note the step function continues on to infinity with a value of 1 - this is because we do not know the end date for one of the records.

```
# define hourly buckets as pandas PeriodIndex
hour_buckets = pd.period_range("2022-03-10 1:00", "2022-03-10 5:00", freq="H")

# integrate the step function over the hourly buckets
total_per_hour = sf.slice(hour_buckets).integral()
```

`total_per_hour` is a `pandas.Series` of `pandas.Timedelta` values and indexed by a `pandas.IntervalIndex`.  It looks like this

```
[2022-03-10 01:00:00, 2022-03-10 02:00:00)   0 days 00:12:00
[2022-03-10 02:00:00, 2022-03-10 03:00:00)   0 days 01:10:00
[2022-03-10 03:00:00, 2022-03-10 04:00:00)   0 days 01:31:00
[2022-03-10 04:00:00, 2022-03-10 05:00:00)   0 days 01:00:00
[2022-03-10 05:00:00, 2022-03-10 06:00:00)   0 days 01:18:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If you want a dataframe format where only the left side of the interval is referenced, and time is given as seconds, then use the following

```
pd.DataFrame({
    "init_date":total_per_hour.index.left,
    "seconds":total_per_hour.dt.total_seconds().values,
})
```

**to summarise**

The solution is

```
import staircase as sc

hour_buckets = pd.period_range("2022-03-10 1:00", "2022-03-10 5:00", freq="H")
total_per_hour = sc.Stairs(df, start="start_date", end="end_date").slice(hour_buckets).integral()

# optional
total_per_hour = pd.DataFrame({
    "init_date":total_per_hour.index.left,
    "seconds":total_per_hour.dt.total_seconds().values,
})
```

**note 1**

In your expected answer you do not have values for `2022-03-10 04:00:00`.

This seems inconsistent with the fact that time for trip `905783` (with no end date) is being included for `2022-03-10 03:00:00` but not subsequent hours.

The solution proposed here includes 3600s for `2022-03-10 04:00:00` and `2022-03-10 05:00:00` which is why it differs from the expected solution in the original question.

**note 2**

If your dataframe has a "driver" column and you want to tally time per driver then the following will work

```
def make_total_by_hour(df_):
    return sc.Stairs(df_, "start_date", "end_date").slice(hour_buckets).integral()

total_per_hour = (
    df.groupby("driver")
    .apply(make_total_by_hour)
    .melt(ignore_index=False)
    .reset_index()
)
```

**note:** I am the creator of staircase. Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.